# How to write elements in nested children of a JSON file using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file like this.

```
{

    "posts": [{
        "id": 0,
        "title": "title1",
        "author": "CIQ",
        "views": 100,
        "reviews": 31
    }],
    "authors": [{
        "id": 0,
        "first_name": "Commerce",
        "last_name": "IQ",
        "posts": 45
    }]
}
```

I want to write the values in nested children of JSON eg. Add the following Post and save the same JSON file.

```
   {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "title2",
        "author": "CIQ2",
        "views": 100,
        "reviews": 31
    }
```

The final file will look like.

```
{
"posts": [{
    "id": 0,
    "title": "title1",
    "author": "CIQ",
    "views": 100,
    "reviews": 31
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "title2",
    "author": "CIQ2",
    "views": 100,
    "reviews": 3
}],
"authors": [{
    "id": 0,
    "first_name": "Commerce",
    "last_name": "IQ",
    "posts": 45
}]
```

}

I am using the below script for writing the file.

```
with open(file_path, 'r+') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
            data['posts'].append(new_post)
            json_file.write(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=True))
```

problem with this script is it appends the data after the end of the file. as shown in the image.
[image]

Please suggest some apporach.

Answer (score 0):

> problem with this script is it appends the data after the end of the file.

Yes, that's what mode `r+` means. Please read the documentation.

> Please suggest some approach

Read the file with mode `r`, make the changes, and then overwrite the file using mode `w` (in a separate `with` block).

Answer (score 0):

we can make it by reading and writing it separately.

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

data['posts'].append(new_post)

with open(file_path, 'w') as data_file:
    data = json.dump(data, data_file)
```